# My testcafe browser is not closing, when I disable the screenshots from command line

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

My testcafe browser is not closing, when I disable the screenshots from the command line

I an npm script like this

`"api:dev": "cross-env ENV=dev testcafe \"chrome\" automation_suite/tests --disable-screenshots --fixture-meta FixtureType=IntegrationTests,TestType=API_TESTS,ProjectName=PR"`,

When I am running the tests, once after the execution is completed, the testcafe browser is not closing.
If I removed the `--disable-screenshots` then the browser is closed and execution getting completed.

I am not sure what mistake I am doing! I just want to disable the screenshots, as I am running the API tests and testcafe will take a screenshot of the blank page.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We will be happy to help you and diagnose this problem, However, I was unable to reproduce it.
Submit a bug report here https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md
and add your environment information there, as well as a sample project and tests so that we can suggest a solution for you.